# Set data from input field into link

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to have option that user previews the item that he/she is saving.

For example I have this:

```
<p>ID</p>
<input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" required>
<a href="#">Preview</a>
```

In my web.php I have defined the route for this:

```
Route::get('/preview/{id}', 'CampaignController@preview');
```

How can I achieve this?
Btw form is not working because this is already in a form. And when I try submit this, the complete form is submitted.

How can I change '#' to something that user enters into input field? So it can be `/preview/something`

Comment: Add a click handler to the link, that reads the value from the input field, and adds it to the partial URL …?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this example:

```
<a href="{{ url("/preview/" . $something) }}">Preview</a>
```